# SHACL - Attribute is optional, but if it exists, it has to have once a specific value

Tags: validation, rdf, linked-data, shacl

a class has an optional attribute. If you use this attribute, you have to set it once to a specific value. All other uses of this attribute are not restricted.

The real world example is `dcat:themeTaxonomy` used in `dcat:Catalog` in DCAT-AP. If used, it has to be set to `<http://publications.europa.eu/resource/authority/data-theme>` but the cardinality is `*`, so you are allowed to use other values.

Other use-cases would be a language skills. You have to state you overall skill-level, but when you do, you can add hearing, speaking or reading skills.

I am trying to check this constraint with SHACL.

The basic idea is:
I have a property shape with the path to the attribute. There I use `sh:or`. Either the `sh:maxCount` is `0` or the `sh:minCount` is `1`. In the second case a `sh:qualifiedValueShape` would check the additional conditions:

## Shapes

```
(omitted urls to not look like spam)

ex:valueIfExists
    sh:message "Custom message for ex:valueIfExists!" ;
    sh:path ex:optionalValue ;

    sh:or ( [
            sh:maxCount 0;
        ] [
            sh:minCount 1;
            sh:qualifiedValueShape [
                sh:path ex:is ;
                sh:hasValue "ok" ;
            ] ;
            sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
        ] ) ;
.

ex:mainShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass ex:TestClass ;
    sh:message "Custom message in mainShape!" ;

    sh:property ex:valueIfExists;
.
```

## Test data

```
(omitted urls to not look like spam)

ex:Test_OK_nothing
    a ex:TestClass ;
.

ex:Test_OK_1
    a ex:TestClass ;
    ex:optionalValue [ex:is "ok"] ;
.

ex:Test_OK_1_2
    a ex:TestClass ;
    ex:optionalValue [ex:is "ok"] ;
    ex:optionalValue [ex:is "other 1"] ;
    ex:optionalValue [ex:is "other 2"] ;
.

ex:Test_Not_OK
    a ex:TestClass ;
    ex:optionalValue [ex:is "other 1"] ;
    ex:optionalValue [ex:is "other 2"] ;
.
```

With this setup I get the following error:

```
VALIDATION FAILURE: Cannot find validator for constraint component http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#MaxCountConstraintComponent
```

so SHACL doesn't want me to use min and maxCount at this position. Fine, I am not fixated on that, but I have no idea left on how to solve the problem.

Has anyone a solution?

Comment: The "Cannot find validator" error looks very wrong, as if something isn't right with the setup. What API is this?

Comment: It's within the https://shacl.org/playground/

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to a common confusion about the usage of `sh:or`. According to the specification `sh:or` provides a *list of shapes to validate the value nodes against*, i.e., it cannot be applied to one of the property shapes of the value nodes. Property shapes are limited to at most one value for `sh:path`.

In order to define the constraint in question, we should instead consider the `sh:or` as part of the `mainShape` and provide the list of acceptable property shapes there. For example:

```
ex:valueIfExists
    sh:message "Custom message for ex:valueIfExists!" ;
    sh:path ex:optionalValue ;
    sh:minCount 1 ;
    sh:qualifiedValueShape [
        sh:path ex:is ;
        sh:hasValue "ok" ;
    ] ;
    sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
.

ex:valueIfNotExists
    sh:message "Custom message for ex:valueIfNotExists!" ;
    sh:path ex:optionalValue ;
    sh:maxCount 0 ;
.

ex:mainShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass ex:TestClass ;
    sh:message "Custom message in mainShape!" ;

    sh:or (
        [ sh:property ex:valueIfExists ]
        [ sh:property ex:valueIfNotExists ]
    )
.
```